# CentOS 6, VBox host - high CPU usage when idle

Tags: macos, centos, virtualbox, cpu-usage, centos6

I'm running a CentOS 6.2 install as a guest in VirtualBox (4.1.8) from a Mac OS (10.7.2) host. While the CentOS guest is idle, the Mac host is showing CPU usage from VirtualBox as around 25%.

The VirtualBox FAQs note that "divider=10" can be added to the kernel options for CentOS 5.x, but it appears the kernel is different in CentOS 6 and this has no effect.

Does any one have any recommendations for how I can make the guest and host work together so that when they are idle they aren't consuming a lot of CPU time?

Comment: Probably best to move to: http://unix.stackexchange.com as this is purely a configuration issue and not a programming one.

Comment: Thank for pointing out the "divider=10". That solved my problem.